# How to use cron with views cache?

Tags: views, caching, cron

I have a dashboard with about seven views that are each very expensive. Most of the views can be computed hourly, but I would prefer cron to run them rather than the unfortunate user. How can I have cron refresh the views cache and never a user?

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should work:

1. Set the Views to cache data.
2. Implement `hook_cron()`, and delete the cached data from the `cache_views` and `cache_views_data` tables.
3. Programmatically request the URL which contains the expensive Views to rebuild them (this could be done via CURL, `file_get_contents()`, etc.)

Comment: Recommend using [httprl](https://drupal.org/project/httprl)'s non blocking mode when doing the HTTP requests.

Comment: @mikeytown2 - that's an interesting library, thanks for posting. Personally, I'd go with something lighter (in this case), such as [this example](http://darklaunch.com/2013/03/23/php-non-blocking-fopen-file-get-contents-using-stream-set-blocking), but I can definitely see the appeal of proper parallel requests.

Answer (score 1):

I implement things like that as a drush script, which I think invoke from a crontab.  Something like would be a start:

```
$cids = array(...); // the $cid list that you want to nuke

foreach ($cids as $cid) {
  cache_clear_all($cid, 'cache_views'); // may want to also do {cache_views_data}
}

$urls = array(...); // the URLs w/ the views that you just cleared

foreach ($urls as $url) {
  $url = url($url, array('absolute' => TRUE)); // if needed
  cache_clear_all($url, 'cache_page');
  $request = drupal_http_request($url);
}
```

I then call it as

```
0 * * * * /path/to/drush -u 1 scr /path/to/script.php
```

from my crontab.

Doing it from crontab instead of Drupal cron can help eliminate PHP timeouts.

Comment: Both answers seem good but this might be a little more flexible. The views I want to blast are private to their users. How will the required authentication be handled?

Comment: @JoeBeuckman Not sure about that one.  Instead of fetching the URL, you may need to use the Views API to instantiate the view, pass in the $account, and then generate the rendered HTML.  You may also have to loop through your users.